# Python 3 - How to switch the case of a dictionary then adding numeric values

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So I have this string

```
"Hello"
```

I want to convert that to an uppercase dictionary with empty values
something like:

```
{ "H":0, "E":0, "L":0, "L":0, "O":0 }
```

and then I want to apply a range of values into the value slots using a for loop:

```
{ "H":1, "E":2, "L":3, "L":4, "O":5 }
```

and finally, use these values to print back out the letter with their assigned values, something like this:

```
"HEELLLLLLLOOOOO"
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? Also note that depending on what version of Python you're using, dictionaries may or may not guarantee a certain order.

Comment: You know that you cannot have two times the same key inside of a dictionary? So getting `{ "H":0, "E":0, "L":0, "L":0, "O":0 }` is impossible.

Comment: To complete @Carcigenicate the order guarantee was declared to be part of language spec with Python 3.7. Of course if you rely on that, your code is not retro-compatible with older Python versions. Also it looks that the change was motivated by related conveniences described in [PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/#abstract) more than because of insertion order (like kwargs order and attributes order, because dicts are used for that).

Comment: Ok, I don't mean to go off the beaten path, but ... I don't understand ...

I have asked just a few questions and they always get negative ratings?

I tried to search this out, I tagged it, I am new to python and tried to make the question and title clear ... 

Can anyone help me understand why I get this negative feedback ?

I thought we are supposed to ask questions to the community ?

I am trying to learn and understand programming ... very confused

Answer (score 2):

You get the first dictionary with

```
>>> s = "Hello"
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(s.upper(), 0)
>>> d
>>> {'E': 0, 'H': 0, 'L': 0, 'O': 0}
```

Note that the key `'L'` appears only once because dictionary keys are unique.

Your second desired dictionary is therefore impossible to create.

But if you only care about the final string, creating any dict is unnecessary, because:

```
>>> ''.join(c*i for i, c in enumerate(s.upper(), 1))
>>> 'HEELLLLLLLOOOOO'
```

If this looks complicated, just use a simple `for` loop.

```
>>> to_join = []
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s.upper(), 1):
...:    to_join.append(c*i)
...:    
>>> result = ''.join(to_join)
>>> result
>>> 'HEELLLLLLLOOOOO'
```

Comment: yes, +1 but their first dict also contains double L and no guarantees on the order either (prior to 3.7)

Comment: While this is a good answer I think there's an arguable case against answering a question with virutally no effort from OP's end...